# SSRS customized pie chart color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a doubt here,

I need to show a pie-chart in SSRS, for the student results according to their status(Pass/Fail).......I have only 4 conditions Male-pass,Male-fail,Female-pass,Female-fail,I need to show these things with my own color,

for this am using the switch condition as

```
=Switch(
((Fields!Gender.Value = "Male")&(Fields!Status.Value="Pass")), "Blue",
((Fields!Gender.Value = "Male")&(Fields!Status.Value="Fail")), "HotPink",
((Fields!Gender.Value = "Female")&(Fields!Status.Value="Fail")), "Orange",
((Fields!Gender.Value = "Female")&(Fields!Status.Value="Pass")),"LimeGreen" )
```

but in the preview it shows only the default color set, not the customized one, can anyone fix this one...thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using something like

```
 =IIf((Fields!Gender.Value = "Male") and (Fields!Status.Value="Pass"),"Green", 
IIf((Fields!Gender.Value = "Male") and(Fields!Status.Value="Fail"),"Red" ,
IIf((Fields!Gender.Value = "Female") and (Fields!Status.Value="Fail") ,"Blue",
(Fields!Gender.Value = "Female") and (Fields!Status.Value="Pass"),"Yellow","Orange"
,"#00000000"))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get it working using the Switch statement as well. The problem with your expression is that the logical "and" operator in SSRS is **And**, not ampersand.  In SSRS, a single ampersand is used for concatenating strings.  So your expression is concatenating the string representation of the two boolean results, resulting in strings like TrueFalse.  This should actually giving an error on the Switch evaluation.

A correct Switch statement would be this:

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Gender.Value = "Male" And Fields!Status.Value="Pass", "Blue",
    Fields!Gender.Value = "Male" And Fields!Status.Value="Fail", "HotPink",
    Fields!Gender.Value = "Female" And Fields!Status.Value="Fail", "Orange",
    Fields!Gender.Value = "Female" And Fields!Status.Value="Pass","LimeGreen"
    , True, "SomeOtherColor"
)
```

I've also added an "else" part to the switch in case some records are not covered by the other conditions. If you're 100% sure that won't happen, you can remove the line that starts with "True". But it shouldn't hurt to keep it either.

More info: [Pie Chart Techniques (look for Custom Coloring chapter)](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/10/25/pie-chart-techniques/)